# Does the standard ruby logger have an "ignore" input?

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec

I'm trying to write a spec test with no info to stdout - not even STDERR.

Is it easily possible to instantiate a Logger with an IOObject that throws away the data passed to it in all circumstances, without monkeypatching the logger?

If so, is this common practice or should I simply use STDERR?

Regards,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could create a logger for the null device:

```
logger = Logger.new(IO::NULL)
```

or set a high logging severity threshold:

```
logger.level = Logger::ERROR
```